# Changing Text on DataTable depending on Fields

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables. I have a table row `status` that loops `<td>#dateFormat(someprocessTable.Date_Complete, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>`, when this loops it will either have a date or be NULL. As of right now if it is NULL then it shows PROCESSING and if it has a date it shows COMPLETED with this JS line

```
{ 
              "data": "Date_Complete",
              "render": function(data){
              return ((data) ? "COMPLETED" : "PROCESSING");
              }
            },
```

I need to figure out how to have it say EXEMPT if instead of processing if the `RMKS` row is saying that its Exempt with no date for `Date_Complete`. If there is a date for `Date_Complete` and `Rmks` is Exempt then it should still say COMPLETED. Would this be possible to do on the JS side?

**HTML**

```
<table id="processing1" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th><b>ITEM ID</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>DEALER ID</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>DATE RECEIVED</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>OP ID</b></th>
        <th><b>DUE DATE</b></th>
        <th><b>STATUS</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>LATE</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>CLOSED BY</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>RMKS</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>PROCESSING LOCATION</b></th>
        <th><b>QTY</b></th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <cfoutput query="someprocessTable">                     
    <tr>
        <td class="details-control"></td>
        <td class="LAlign">#id#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#someprocessTable.name#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#dateFormat(someprocessTable.Date_Received, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#getop_id(op_id)#</td>
        <td>#dateFormat(someprocessTable.Date_Due, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        <td>#dateFormat(someprocessTable.Date_Complete, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#Completed_Late#</td>
        <cfif len(Closed_by)>
        <td style="display:none;">#getClosed_by(Closed_by)#</td>
        <cfelse>
        <td style="display:none;">#Closed_by#</td>
        </cfif>
        <td style="display:none;">#Rmks#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#Processing_Location#</td>
        <td class="CAlign">#Item_Count#</td>
    </tr>                      
   </cfoutput>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
function format ( d ) {

    return '<div class="slider">'+
           'Item ID: '+d.id+'<br>'+
           'Dealer: '+d.dealerID+'<br>'+
           'Date Received: '+d.Date_Received+'<br>'+
           'Checked In: '+d.op_id+'<br>'+
           'Date Due: '+d.Date_Due+'<br>'+
           'Date Complete: '+ ((d.Date_Complete) ? d.Date_Complete : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Completed Late: '+ ((d.Completed_Late) ? d.Completed_Late : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Completed By: '+ ((d.Closed_by) ? d.Closed_by : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Remarks: '+ ((d.Rmks) ? d.Rmks : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Location: '+d.Processing_Location+'<br>'+
           'Item Count: '+d.Item_Count+'<br>'+
           '</div>';
    }
// Setup the page once it has loaded.

$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#processing1').DataTable( {

        "columns": [ 
            {
                "class":          "details-control",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ""
            },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "dealerID" },
            { "data": "Date_Received" },
            { "data": "op_id" },
            { "data": "Date_Due" },
            { 
              "data": "Date_Complete",
              "render": function(data){
              return ((data) ? "COMPLETED" : "PROCESSING");
              }
            },
            { "data": "Completed_Late" },
            { "data": "Closed_by" },
            { "data": "Rmks" },
            { "data": "Processing_Location" },
            { "data": "Item_Count" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], "searchable": false }
        ],
        "sDom": '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"f><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"ip>>>',
        select: {
            style: 'single'
        },
        scrollY:        250,
        deferRender:    true,
        scroller:       true,
        //scrollCollapse: true,
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ <label for='processing_length'><strong>records per page</strong></label>",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "«",
                "sNext": "»",
            }
        }

    });
```

[image]

This picture show Remarks Exempt so it should show the status as EXEMPT instead of PROCESSING but once there is a date in Date_Complete it should read COMPLETED
[image]

**The different possibilities:** 
Date for `Date_Complete` and `Rmks` Exempt = COMPLETED 
Date for `Date_Complete` and `Rmks` Null = COMPLETED 
Null Date for `Date_Complete` and `Rmks` Exempt = EXEMPT 
Null Date for `Date_Complete` and `Rmks` Null = PROCESSING

Comment: I'm not really understanding.  Which of those items in your screenshot should have status "EXEMPT" instead of what it actually says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function is given as value to [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option, one of the parameters contains row data.

Use the code below to include in condition data from another column:

```js
"render": function(data, type, row, meta){
   if(data && (row['Rmks'] === 'Exempt' || !row['Rmks'])){
      data = "COMPLETED";
   } else if (!data && row['Rmks'] === 'Exempt'){
      data = "EXEMPT";
   } else if (!data && !row['Rmks']){
      data = "PROCESSING";
   } else {
      data = "";
   }

   return data;
}
```

Comment: @Vicki, sorry it was not clear from the original question, but you get an idea. I will update the code.

Comment: Thanks for the example! What does it mean when dreamweaver says "Rmks is better written in dot notation"? it still works regardless was just curious what they were talking about

Comment: @Vicki, `row['Rmks']` could be written as `row.Rmks` but dotted notation doesn't allow certain characters in names.